# facebook prophet : how to decompose the result into seasonality and trend components

Tags: time-series, facebook-prophet

Facebook prophet is additive model. It contains trend and seasonality. For example, sale forecasting of Facebook prophet is 1200. How do i find the value of seasonality, trend and regressor. For example seasonality components is 300 trend is 500 and regressor is 400. How do i find each value for each components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.predict(future)` will return a `df` with trend, seasonality and regressor information on historical data.